# C# NOT (~) bit wise operator returns negative values

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, bit

Why does C#'s bitwise `NOT` operator return `(the_number*-1)-1`?

```
byte a = 1;
Console.WriteLine(~a); //equals -2
byte b = 9;
Console.WriteLine(~b); //equals -10
// Shouldn't a=0 and b=6?
```

How would I do this in C#?

```
9 = 0b1001 -> NOT
  = 0b0110 = 6
```

Comment: You do realize that `byte` has 8 bits, thus the binary representation is of 9 is 0b00001001?

Comment: -2 is actually alright, since ints use ... well, @knittl just said it below.

Comment: This isn't specific to C# - the CPUs themselves work this way

Comment: Recommended reading: http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bitwise operations return a value of type `int` (signed). Signed integers use [*two's-complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers. Sign extension is used when going from byte to int.

```
byte a = 1; // 0b00000001
int notA = ~a; // 0b11111110 = -128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 = -2 (actually 0b11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110)

byte b = 9; // 0b00001001
int notB = ~9; // 0b11110110 = -128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 4 + 2 = -10 (actually 0b11111111 11111111 11111111 11110110)
```

Casting back to byte will give you the "expected" result for `0b11110110`

```
byte notB = unchecked((byte)(~b)); // 0b11110110 = 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 4 + 2
Console.WriteLine(notB); // 246
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that the leading bits are also inverted:

```
00001001
NOT
11110110
```

It looks like you want to *mask* those:

```
byte b = 9;
Console.WriteLine(~b & 0xf);  // should output 6
```