# vb6 ORing hex values constants?

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

Trying to convert this to C# but confused on when it OR's some hex value constants when setting into another constant.

```
Public Const STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = &H1F0000
Public Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000
Public Const KEY_CREATE_LINK = &H20
Public Const KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = &H4
Public Const KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = &H8
Public Const KEY_NOTIFY = &H10
Public Const KEY_QUERY_VALUE = &H1
Public Const KEY_SET_VALUE = &H2
Public Const KEY_READ = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ Or _
                      KEY_QUERY_VALUE Or KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS _
                     Or KEY_NOTIFY) And (Not SYNCHRONIZE))
```

c#?:

```
public const int KEY_READ = ((STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ || KEY_QUERY_VALUE || KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS || KEY_NOTIFY) & (!SYNCHRONIZE));
```

Comment: in C#, use the bitwise operators | (for Or), & (for And) and ! (for Not)

Comment: Just use `|` instead of `Or`

Comment: But it says you can't use || when comparing two ints.

Comment: Replace your double || with a single |

Comment: @user3542679 that's why we suggested to use the bitwise (single pipe) operator :)

Comment: Haha that worked. And then at the end operator ! cannot be applied to type int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the bitwise operations |, &, and ~ as equivalents to VB `And`, `Or`, and `Not`.
Observe that I specified the type as `uint` (unsigned integer), to avoid side effects due to the internal representation of the `int` type in .NET ([more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881635/1132334)).

```
public const uint READ_CONTROL = 0x20000;
public const uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;
public const uint STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x1F0000;
public const uint SYNCHRONIZE = 0x100000;
public const uint KEY_CREATE_LINK = 0x20;
public const uint KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY = 0x4;
public const uint KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS = 0x8;
public const uint KEY_NOTIFY = 0x10;
public const uint KEY_QUERY_VALUE = 0x1;
public const uint KEY_SET_VALUE = 0x2;
public const uint KEY_READ = (
    (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_NOTIFY) 
    & (~SYNCHRONIZE)
);
```

Comment: what does the ~ do here?

Comment: public const int READ_CONTROL = 0x20000 public const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL;

Comment: Thank you, for this perfect answer =]

Comment: the [unary ~ operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66(v=vs.100).aspx) inverts each bit (I was wrong in my initial comment to suggest the ! operator, which is the logical negation for booleans).