# Why isn't ~ of 6 = 1 since it flips the bits?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

see example below. I was either expecting it to be 1 or 249 if we account for the whole bits in the byte type.

I read the sources but I can't figure out why I am not able to grasp it.

```
byte num1 = 6;
byte num2 = 12;
Assert.IsTrue(~num1 == 1);
Assert.IsTrue(~num2 == 3);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# NOT (~) bit wise operator returns negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37881537/c-sharp-not-bit-wise-operator-returns-negative-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` operator converts type to `int`. If you want `byte` - use cast:

```
byte num1 = 6;
byte num2 = 12;
Console.WriteLine((byte)~num1);
Console.WriteLine((byte)~num2);
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I should have paid attention to that. But why would (int)~num1
be -7

Comment: @AmandaSai98b `(byte)6` in binary is `110`, `(int)6` in binary is `00000000000000000000000000000110`, `(int)~6` in binary is `11111111111111111111111111111001` that is `-7` as signed integer